# How to convert Text Column to Date Column in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, date, datetime

I was given a date column in the form of 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss UTC'. I have tried using cast and convert to date, datetime, and timestamp, but they all only return the YYYY. Is there any way to return the date correctly from this type of string? I also would like this NewDate column to be added to my table for future use.

Below is the code I have tried

```
select OrigDate, cast(OrigDate as timestamp) as NewDate from MyTable
```

Comment: With no DB/SQL engine tagging and no data sample there is not much to be done.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Sorry, I am using DB Browser for SQLite

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no special datatype for dates, which can be stored as text or numbers (julian days or epoch timestamp); instead, it has a set of [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) that operate on these values.

SQLite recognizes `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` as a valid date format, so to make your strings valid SQLite date formats, you just need to remove the trailing " UTC":

```
select OrigDate, substring(OrigDate, -4) NewDate  from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new column with name `NewDate` to the table like this:

```
alter table MyTable add NewDate text;
```

As you can see the data type defined is `text` because there is no `date` or `datetime` data type in SQLite.
Then you can *populate/update* this column with the *local time* that each of your *UTC* datetimes already have in the column `OrigDate` with the use of the function [`datetime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
update MyTable
set NewDate = datetime(substr(OrigDate, 1, 19), 'localtime');
```

See a simplified [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3e632c/2).